# How to Improve This Self-Joins

Tags: sql, oracle, self-join

I am learning Oracle SQL by working with its primitive `HR` schema where there is `EMPLOYEES` table which has three columns that I'm mainly interested in: `MANAGER_ID`, which is basically a self reference to `EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID`, `DEPARTMENT_ID`, and `SALARY`. (You can find the [schema diagram](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/COMSC/diagrams.htm#CIHGFFHI) and [schema objects](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/COMSC/scripts.htm#COMSC00020) here).

I wish, for each employee, to retrieve his/her `SALARY`, alongside of employee's manager's departmental average salary. For instance, if we have the following (`EMPLOYEE_ID = 140` is the interested party here):

```
+-------------+--------+---------------+------------+
| EMPLOYEE_ID | SALARY | DEPARTMENT_ID | MANAGER_ID |
+-------------+--------+---------------+------------+
| 140         | 12000  | 50            | 110        |
| 110         | 20000  | 60            | 101        |
| 156         | 18000  | 60            | 101        |
| 175         | 15000  | 60            | 105        |
| 320         | 24000  | 60            | 105        |
+-------------+--------+---------------+------------+
```

I am interested in obtaining an average salary of all the managers (not all other non-managerial employees) in *department* where **employee's manager** works at (in this case, `DEPARTMENT_ID =`**60**), and compare it with *employee*'s (in this case, **140**). In a sample data above, the output should be:

```
+-------------+--------+-------------+-------------+------------+
| EMPLOYEE_ID | SALARY | AVG_MGR_SAL | MGR_DEPT_ID | MANAGER_ID |
+-------------+--------+-------------+-------------+------------+
| 140         | 12000  | 19250       | 60          | 110        |
+-------------+--------+-------------+-------------+------------+
```

where we have four (4) managers working in department *60*, and *$19250* being calculated as (20000 + 18000 + 15000 + 24000) / 4. I have come up with the following query that seems to work (and excludes those employees that don't have a manager):

```
select
    employee_id
    , salary employee_salary
    , trunc(mgr_info.avg_manager_salary_per_dept, 0) emp_manager_avg_sal_dept
    , mgr_info.manager_dept_id
    , mgr_info.manager_id
from employees
join (
      select
          e1.employee_id manager_id
          , e1.department_id manager_dept_id
          , e1.salary manager_salary
          , avg(e1.salary) over (partition by e1.department_id) avg_manager_salary_per_dept
      from employees e1
      join (
            select distinct manager_id 
            from employees 
            where manager_id is not null
           ) mgr_ids
          on e1.employee_id = mgr_ids.manager_id
      ) mgr_info
    on employees.manager_id = mgr_info.manager_id
order by employee_id
```

However, I feel like that there should be a better way of getting the same result with fewer self-joins. Is there a way to get a better performance?

Comment: Can you show us what a record looks like for a manager?

Comment: Please clarify... for the example you gave, you want the average salary for department 60, but not for ALL employees in that department, just for the employees who are managers? (Including, of course, the manager of the original employee.)

Comment: Please at least show a complete sample input and output so we don't have to guess.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - I understand the request to see sample output. What do you mean by "sample input"? What is confusing about HR schema, EMPLOYEES table?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Added a sample input/output data

Comment: @mathguy Correct. Average salary of *only* managers in department **60**.

Comment: OK - that's what I did in my solution (after I realized that was what you asked for).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this... You only need one join, you can compute the average salary for the manager's department on the "manager" copy of the table. I only included a few columns, you may need more, or fewer, but I believe the core of what you wanted is covered.

(NOTE: Edited since I realized I missed one detail in the requirement)

```
select e.employee_id   as employee_id,
       e.salary        as employee_salary,
       m.employee_id   as manager_id,
       m.department_id as manager_dept_id,
       m.avg_salary    as avg_sal_of_mgr_dept
from hr.employees e inner join
       ( select employee_id, department_id, 
                avg(salary) over (partition by department_id) as avg_salary
         from   hr.employees
         where  employee_id in (select manager_id from hr.employees)
       ) m
on e.manager_id = m.employee_id
;
```

Comment: `I am interested in obtaining an average salary of all the managers in department 60 and compare it with the employee (in this case, 140).`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen An average salary for all the **managers** in department 60. I get that. Why the average of **employee** salaries? Also, why is this under my Answer and not under yours?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - I looked again at the OP's requirement and his sample output (partial as it is) and at his attempted solution, they are all in agreement. For every employee who has a manager, he wants to show that employee, his or her salary (individually!), the manager id, the manager's department (which sometimes is different from the employee's!) and the average salary for the manager's department. (However, I just noticed he didn't want ALL the employees in that department... so my solution is incorrect too.)

Comment: I assumed that the manager is in the same department as his employees.  If this be not the case, then IMO the question has bad table design, because it will be a lot of unnecessary work to join all over the place for such a simple query.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The manager is not in the same department as the employee (not necessarily). The schema HR is on every Oracle installation, you can take a look for yourself. The OP did not invent this schema.

Comment: You are right about the joins - I thought my solution has only one join, but of course it has two (the IN condition); unavoidable, since he only wants the average of **managers'** salaries in the same department as the employee's manager.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option which uses a series of joins to get your result:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.EMPLOYEE_ID,
                t1.SALARY,
                t1.DEPARTMENT_ID,
                COALESCE(t2.SALARY, 0.0) AS ManagerAvgSal
FROM employees t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT e1.DEPARTMENT_ID, AVG(e1.SALARY) AS SALARY
    FROM employees e1
    WHERE e1.EMPLOYEE_ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT MANAGER_ID FROM employees)
    GROUP BY e1.DEPARTMENT_ID
) t2
    ON t1.DEPARTMENT_ID = t2.DEPARTMENT_ID
```

Comment: Why the employee average salary? I didn't see that in the requirement.

Comment: Not equivalent: the original statement joins employees to managers, and not based on department - check the sample data again.  Some other differences in result columns and ordering.  `IN` doesn't require `DISTINCT`, and it's possible that the two forms would reduce to the same plan anyways (if the output data was the same).

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Given the poor explanation in the OP, this is the best I could do at the time.  If it updates, so will I.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - that is unfair. What was unclear in the explanation? Everything makes perfect sense. If you are not familiar with the HR schema, that is definitely not the OP's fault.

Comment: @mathguy A SO question needs to be able to stand on its own two feet.  It is _not_ acceptable to give a link to an outside schema.  Suppose Oracle stops shipping the HR schema 3 years from now.  Would this question be useful to anyone?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - any serious Oracle professional will disagree with you on this. The HR schema has existed from version 1 of Oracle (I believe) and I also believe Oracle has promised it will ship with every version in the future. The question absolutely stands on its two feet - to anyone who has more than a few months of experience with Oracle specifically (not with SQL or databases in general).

Comment: @mathguy So you're saying that SO should ignore any _other_ DB professional, e.g. a SQL Server admin?  Then the rest of the community should go look up the schema?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Added links to Oracle (12c) HR schema and diagrams.